# PreLinkEvent failing with error MSB3073 in Release config

Tags: cmake, msbuild, linker, linker-errors, msvc12

Seeing this failure only with release config. I see a lot of people have asked similar question but in their case, the issue is seen during Postbuild and also in almost all the cases, the error is more meaningful.

```
PreLinkEvent:
  Auto build dll exports
  setlocal
  cd C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  C:
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  C:\cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64\bin\cmake.exe -E __create_def C:/myfolder/examples/windows/calculator/windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win/calculator.dir/Release/exports.def C:/myfolder/examples/windows/calculator/windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win/calculator.dir/Release//objects.txt
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
  :cmEnd
  endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
  :cmErrorLevel
  exit /b %1
  :cmDone
  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
  :VCEnd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: cd C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: C: [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: C:\cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64\bin\cmake.exe -E __create_def C:/myfolder/examples/windows/calculator/windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win/calculator.dir/Release/exports.def C:/myfolder/examples/windows/calculator/windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win/calculator.dir/Release//objects.txt [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(148,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1073741819. [C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\myfolder\examples\windows\calculator\windows_Release_aarch64.cmake.win\calculator.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

I compared the PreLinkEvent lines in Debug and Release and they are exactly same except for the folder name. Any leads are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved after removing /GL compiler flag. I added it only for release configuration, hence the issue was not seen for debug configuration.